# Confusion over SAT question

Tags: pronouns

[image]

[image]

The answer is B, but I am confused on why D does not work. Is this just a case where its proper to have a pronoun? If so, how does this rule work and when is it appropriate? Doesn't this sentence, for example, operate the same way: "The Spanish Flu can cause death." Isn't this sentence better like it is than "The Spanish Flu can cause one's death."

Comment: There is no "right" or "wrong" in many of these cases, just some options that are "better" than others.

Comment: You had a poor SAT question, carelessly composed. All except C are acceptable. Not worth worrying about.